# Render vs Viewport render discrepancy

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I tried following this tutorial , but my render on the left isn't as whispy as the viewport render.  Is there a setting I'm missing?
https://youtu.be/EVj1fETtuN8
[image]

Comment: "*following this tutorial*" which one? Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that show the settings for the particles/hair

Answer (score 3):

In your render the hair particles are not subdivided enough, check if these 2 settings match - first is for render, 2nd is for viewport:

[image]

Also in your render it seems there are more hairs rendered, that may be due to children particles and that only a percentage of them is displayed in viewport:

[image]

Lastly if you set the same amount of samples for viewport and render, you should get the same outcome:

[image]